# Mimic other Microsoft provided widgets default configuration behavior

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing a custom dashboard widget and I have a configuration page setup as well. That all works fine except I am trying to mimic the default "Configure Widget" behavior that is seen in other Microsoft provided widgets, as shown in the image below. I can detect when a widget is not configured, but I can't figure out what function to call to make the configuration modal window open. I have tried inspecting the source code of the VSS SDK as well as looking around the internet for examples and documentation but haven't found anything that works yet.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this I decided to try and dig into it further by creating a dashboard with just a single unconfigured Microsoft widget that had the functionality I was looking for and then trying to look through the pile of minified scripts that the page loaded and look for anything that could lead me in the right direction, eventually I found it:

```js
VSS.ready(() => {
    VSS.require(['TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers', 'TFS/Work/RestClient', 'VSS/Service', 'TFS/Dashboards/Services'],
    (WidgetHelpers, WorkRestClient, Service, DashboardServices) => {
        ...
        DashboardServices.WidgetHostService.getService().then((DashboardServiceHost) => {
            DashboardServiceHost.showConfiguration() // This is what you want to hook up to your onClick event to show the widget configuration modal.
        });
        ...
    });
});
```